# Why ListView doesnot show divider

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

For this perticular case i am using default listview layout and I am extending my activity with `ListFragment`. I am having a problem to show divider in listview. I am using the follwing xml file for my listview row formate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@color/windowBackground"
android:padding="2dp" >

       <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <!-- This is Supposed to be the divider -->
      <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/shape" >
      </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The secondlast `RelativeLayout` which is using the `shape.xml` file is supposed to be the divider. `Shape.xml` file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="2px" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

The list data output is fine. I can see data in both `TextViews` but it does not show the divider which is `RelativeLayout` with a background `@drawable/shape`

Comment: why you are using shape.xml for making a line you can use `view` instead of `relative layout` just give height in your `android:layout_height="2dp"`

Comment: @Clairvoyant I know i may use that solution but i was trying to use this shape.xml file.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can set a divider to the ListView by itself instead of adding it in to each item.

Comment: @McAdam331 you mean by calling setDivider(Drawable drawable) function ?

Comment: Or in the XML where ever you have the ListView tag you can do <ListView android:dividerHeight="1px"> or something along those lines, that's what I'm used to doing. You can do it programatically as well though, if you prefer.

Comment: @McAdam331 i dont have any ListView tag in xml. I have mentioned that i am using default Listview layout that why i dont have ListView tag.

Comment: Oooh my mistake. I am so used to just using a Fragment and putting a ListView in XML myself that I sometimes forget about the ListFragment class.

Comment: In a `ListFragment`, you can still call `getListView().setDivider(Drawable drawable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right you could put a divider inside your layout row just like you did but you have to correct it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@color/windowBackground"
android:padding="2dp" >

       <RelativeLayout 
           android:id="@+id/row_id"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <!-- This is Supposed to be the divider -->
      <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@id/row_id"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:background="@color/yourColor" >
      </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or more simple way is to get your listView from the divide and put a divider to it

```
getListView().setDividerHeight(heightOfDivider);
getListView().setDivider(yourDrawable);
```

if any trouble leave a comment

Good luck !

Comment: i know this solution and i will accept your answer. It is the same solution as another person suggested in the very first comment but the main question is why my layout doesnot draw shape which is defined in shape.xml ?

Comment: your shape was not displaying because maybe it was hidden by your row because you did put "layout_below", please try to use the code i put and replace "@color/yourColor" by your shape